# Plotly interactive plot in jupyter notebook slideshow

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly-python

I'm building a presentation using Jupyter Notebook in slideshow mode (and RISE).

Everything works fine till I add an interactive plot with Plotly. I only see the code, no plot.

Is it possible to have an interactive plot using Plotly in Slideshow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line to the `iplot` cell:

```
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as an alternative.

```
import chart_studio
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import chart_studio.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objects as go

chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username='/...', api_key='/...')    # Register on chart_Studio website

trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6]
)

data = [trace]
layout = go.Layout(title="My Plot")

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

### Now, instead of using iplot(), you can use py.plot() to upload your plots to your chart_studio account
# py.plot(fig, filename = 'my_plot', auto_open=True)

display(fig.show())
```

Here is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8l6B.png)